# Read more block is appending /#more-{post_id} to the link

Tags: permalinks, read-more

When I put a `Read More` block, and my post link for instance is `http://admin.com/jobs`, by clicking on `Read More`, it will go to `http://admin.com/jobs/#more-63`. 63 is the post id.

How can I prevent this behavior? I don't want it to append `#more-{pid}` to the post link

Comment: I dont think that is possible.

Comment: read https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#Prevent_Page_Scroll_When_Clicking_the_More_Link

Comment: @Michael It worked! feel free to post an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: no worthy as an answer - just keep searching the docu in the future...